# Breaking out of a nested loop in C

Tags: break

I required a clarification about the break statements in the following code snippet:

1. When control reaches the break with the comment "number 1", the inner loop is exited and control shifts to the following if statement with "flag". Is this correct?
2. When control reaches the second break statement, the function is exited. Is this right?

   ```
   void compute(int n, int numJ) {

   int j, jCount = 0, init, base, check, added = 0, flag = 0;

   init = pow(10, (n - 1)) + 1;

   for(j = 0; j < pow(2, (n - 2)); j++)
   {
       check = init + 10 * convert(j);

       for(base = 2; base <= 10; base++)
       {
           added = decValue(check, base);

           if(!isPrime(added))
               flag += 1;
           else
               break;   //number 1
       }

       if(flag == 9)
       {
           display(check);
           jCount += 1;
       }

       if(jCount == numJ)
           break;    //number 2
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The break statement terminates the execution of the nearest enclosing do, for, switch, or while statement in which it appears. Control passes to the statement that follows the terminated statement.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt88dxx6.aspx)

Thus in the example you provided, if `(jCount == numJ) == true`, then yes, the parent for loop should be exited out of.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the second break statement will break out of the outer loop and reach the end of the function.